# List Box MS Access, Item Addition to Textbox

Tags: sql, listbox, distinct, ms-access-2010

Addition: I am using this query in my List Box in MS Access 2010, to select Distinct values in my list ( in this case, for AOM):

```
SELECT First([Exhibit Recording].ReferenceNo) AS FirstOfReferenceNo, [Exhibit Recording].AOM
FROM [Exhibit Recording]
GROUP BY [Exhibit Recording].AOM;
```

it works fine except that I connected it with the AOM Text box for Data entry with this VB Code :

```
Private Sub txtAOM_AfterUpdate()

  If (VBA.Strings.Len(txtAOM.Value & "") <> 0) Then
     txtAOM.Value = txtAOM.Column(1)
  Else
    txtAOM.Value = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

But instead of the AOM entries being added, the associated ReferenceNo keeps showing up the the AOM textbox.

How can I make the AOM items appear in the AOM Textbox instead of their associated ReferenceNo showing up.

Thanks

I have made a List Box in MS Access 2010. I am using this query for showing up only distinct values from the column (AOM) from which the List Box is getting data:

```
SELECT [Exhibit Recording].ReferenceNo, DISTINCT [Exhibit Recording].AOM
FROM [Exhibit Recording];
```

Now When I am using this an error "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DISTINCT [Exhibit Recording].AOM'." keeps popping up, but disappears when I remove DISTINCT.

Is there any way to have distinct values in a list box and not get that error?

I also tried using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Exhibit Recording].AOM
FROM [Exhibit Recording];
```

The query runs fine, but the text in the listbox disappears and when you click on it it shows a dark band to show that something has been selected. Any way of getting around this ?

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the `Bound Column` property of the List Box to `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by the `.Value` property of a List Box or Combo Box is controlled by the `Bound Column` property. The default is `1`, meaning that the `.Value` will come from the first column of the control's `Row Source` for the selected item. If you want the `.Value` of the List Box to come from the second column of the `Row Source` simply change the `Bound Column` property of the List Box to `2`.